# How do I send a Windows-1255 encoded file using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, character-encoding, iconv

I'm writing an API that creates text files.
It's used by legacy software that requires the files to be with the [Windows 1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) encoding.
I'm creating the content of the file from a good old JavaScript string.

This is the relevant parts of the code I have so far:

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const str = 'Hello world, שלום עולם';
const encoded_str = iconv.encode(str, 'win1255', {addBOM: true});
response.status(200).send('data:text/plain;base64,' + Buffer.from(str, 'binary').toString('base64'));
```

It sends a text file successfully. Its ASCII content is preserved and is shown nicely when I open it in notepad, but any non-ASCII (think: Hebrew) characters are garbled.

I have a gut feeling it has something to do with the base64 conversion.
(the file is later opened using an HTML `<a href="...">` tag)

Comment: Please show the receiving and/or displaying side of this so that your answer can be understood as a correct answer.

Comment: @TomBlodget What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

The reason you're seeing garbled characters has more to do with your Windows settings.

Windows-1255 is an old standard. These days we use UTF (Unicode).
Windows-1255, like other Windows code pages, is 8-bit SBCS.

The first 127 values are ASCII compatible. The other ones take a different meaning based on encoding. Hebrew encodings give them Hebrew meanings, Japaneese give them Japaneese meanings, etc...
There aren't enough bits to represent the wide variety of symbols.

If you go to your Windows settings and define how to treat non-unicode encodings, it will change which meanings the upper 127 numbers take.
Go and set it to Hebrew, and your content won't be garbled anymore.

Further reading: [Joel on Software - The absolute minimum every software developer absolutely positively must know about unicode and character sets, no excuses.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)